# KVM Support for Android Emulator with Amazon AMI

Tags: android, android-emulator, virtualization, kvm, amazon-ami

Hi I want to run Android Emulator using Bitbucket pipeline runner and it needs KVM support machine. Please suggest ami that has KVM support (virtualisation enabled).I tried C5 and Oracle Enterprise Linux. Android Emulator still not supported

```
VERBOSE | Creating empty ext4 cache partition: /root/.android/avd/Pixel_3a_API_24_x86_64.avd/cache.img
Creating filesystem with parameters:
    Size: 69206016
    Block size: 4096
    Blocks per group: 32768
    Inodes per group: 4224
    Inode size: 256
    Journal blocks: 1024
    Label: 
    Blocks: 16896
    Block groups: 1
    Reserved block group size: 7
Created filesystem with 11/4224 inodes and 1302/16896 blocks
VERBOSE | CPU Acceleration: DISABLED
VERBOSE | CPU Acceleration status: KVM requires a CPU that supports vmx or svm
VERBOSE | handleCpuAcceleration: feature check for hvf
detox[973] ERROR: ChildProcessError: `/opt/android/emulator/emulator -verbose -no-audio -no-boot-anim -no-window -gpu swiftshader_indirect -port 16162 @Pixel_3a_API_24_x86_64` failed with code 1
    at ChildProcess.<anonymous> (/opt/atlassian/pipelines/agent/build/node_modules/child-process-promise/lib/index.js:132:23)
    at ChildProcess.emit (events.js:400:28)
    at maybeClose (internal/child_process.js:1058:16)
    at Process.ChildProcess._handle.onexit (internal/child_process.js:293:5)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Please use C5 Bare Metal. Yet the issue is not resolved as I got new error after using this instance type. However, bare metal is the only solution.